# separate cookies of 2 users in the same browser

Tags: php, cookies, browser, authentication, handle

How can I handle cookies of 2 users in one browser? Assume I have 2 users trying to login my registration page on a same browser, then cookies of the last user logged in will be in use for all pages ahead and only one info of a user will be displayed rather than 2 of them. A way to separate 2 cookies in 1 browser would really help me out.

Comment: If there is no need for going back and fourth with the server,  Use local storage instead of cookies.

Comment: set expire time or ask them to logout before they go away:)

Comment: Set a cookie with the users specific ID?

Comment: @JasonBassett mind-blown solution :))) thank you so much